# In Bootstrap, why does the invalid-feedback class increase the width of my input?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My JSFiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jdpzh1g8/

and appears like this:

[image: s]

When I remove this code:

```
<div class="invalid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-fw"></i>Some message about date
</div>
```

My input becomes narrower:

[image]

even though the size of the message ("Some message about date") didn't even take up half the input length.

I would like my input to be the narrower size at all times.

How do I stop the invalid-feedback class from increasing the size of my input?

Comment: If i were you i would use `class="text-danger"` instead of `class="invalid-feedback"`

Answer (score 0):

So I did some research and `invalid-feedback` isn't very good. So instead I used `text-danger`. This is easier and you will have less problems. Here is my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0om7g58y/). Hope this is okay for you :)